# Control to display files and folders tree from an FTP server

Tags: .net, ftp

I'd like to display a tree of all the folders and files on an FTP server.

My question is: is it possible to configure FolderBrowserDialog and OpenFileDialog to read from an FTP location, and if not does anybody know about an existing control that would do that?

I've experimented with the OpenFileDialog and although it can read files from an FTP URI, the folder tree on the left isn't populated with FTP folders and it asks me for connection credentials every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember seeing something like that on code project
(http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FtpBrowseDialog.aspx)

But I haven't looked at the code.  It sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Rob that's exactly what I needed and didn't want to write from scratch.